# Python: if condition for an another function result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.6, spyder

**Solved:** Thanks for your helps. i'm working dictionary and hash codes in one page, and there was a block problem. i thought, my logic is wrong but i checked all page, and i fixed blocks. its works fine right now.

**Here's my problem:**

```
d = {}
d['a'] = 'alpha'
d['b'] = 'beta'

missing_key = 'x' in d
if missing_key == True:
  print ("The key, you are looking for was successfully found!")
else:
  print ("The key, you are looking for was not found!")


print ("Here are keys in database:")
for k, r in enumerate(d.keys(), start=1)
  print ("Key {}: {}".format(k, r))
```

that `for` condition works perfectly. but i cant run that `if` condition. Where am i doing wrong ? Thanks for your help.

**Getting this error:**

```
File "C:/Python/dictionary-hash.py", line 33

if missing_key == True:

IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

> also i'm using "Python 3.6" and "Anaconda Spyder"

Comment: What does 'I can't run that "if" condition' mean? What happens when you try:

Comment: Your condition is inverted. Your code reads `if 'x' in d: print('x was not found')`. I think you meant `if 'x' not in d:`. Your `missing_key` variable is true when the key is _not_ missing.

Comment: As a side note, you almost never want `if missing_key == True:`, just `if missing_key:`.

Comment: The code you've pasted here does not match the code on your computer. There's nothing we can do to help you fix code that already works

Comment: yes. sorry for confusion. my bad. i'm edited my problem right now.

Comment: **unexpected indent** indicates your indent is wrong. Double-check your indent.

Comment: @sct In SO you should not add SOLVED or similar to the title of your question, what you should do is mark the answer that helped you as the correct one, if none of the answers helped you then I invite you to post an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, i'm fixing. sry for that. this's my first subject on StackOverFlow.com. im gonna mark. thx for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the logic in your code. Since the error is an `IndentationError`, it must be because you're using inconsistent indentation on that `if` line. Make sure that the indentation on each line is consistent (using same number of spaces/tabs). Probably there is a space at the beginning of that line that is causing the error.

Comment: thank you. i'm gonna check my work file. i'm using all "dictionary" codes (for ex: `x.items()`, `x.values()`) in one page. probably there's a "block problem" as you say. i thought, python dont accept, that code.